# What should I know in java to be able to create desktop applications?

Tags: java, user-interface

I know core Java and have worked a little with J2EE. But I want start developing Desktop Applications in Java as is done using .NET tools but I don't know where to get started. As I am a beginner, I want to know the following:
1. What should I know in Java to be able to create Desktop based applications?
2. What are the alternatives to Database Servers like Oracle etc. for small scale database driven applications in Java?
3. What is the best RAD tool for such Desktop based Java applications (Windows OS)?

Comment: 1. Swing 2. Files/XML customized data store 3. Netbeans' drag and drop UI :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The former Sun website is a good starting point: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/
2. Take a look at embeddable databases like H2 and HSQL
3. I second @Napul here: Netbeans has a decent GUI builder

Answer (score 1):

First you would want to pick how you want to build your UI. You can use swing, but [this](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/misc/80gui-generator.html) seems to be a fairly large list of alternatives ways to building your UI. There are a lot of other tools out there, I haven't looked that much though, I tend to prefer to just use Swing.

For small dbs you can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). This works very well. I have also used [memcached](http://memcached.org/) but, the data was only needed for the duration of the application.

Answer (score -1):

Download NetBeans or Eclipse IDE,Build Simple applications,thats the way to learn.Just Type in Netbeans or Eclipse in google you will find it all.